# Azure Synapse Private Endpoint Approve

Tags: bash, azure, azure-synapse

Via some Terraform scripts within a CICD process I am trying to create a Managed private Endpoint for an Azure SQL Server Linked service. This is successful using the following code:

```
resource "azurerm_synapse_managed_private_endpoint" "mi_metadata_transform_sql_server_private_endpoint" {
name                 = "mi_synapse_metadata_transform_private_endpoint"
subresource_name     = "sqlServer"
synapse_workspace_id = module.mi_synapse_workspace.synapse_workspace_id
target_resource_id   = azurerm_mssql_server.mi-metadata-transform-sql-server.id}
```

But that leaves the Endpoint in a "Pending Approval State".  So adding the code below which is based on some of our existing code that approves some storage via Bash, I decided to copy that code and adjust accordingly for SQL Server.  And this is where my problem begins.....

```
function enable_sql_private_endpoint {
        endpoints=$(az sql server show --name $1 -g ${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }} --subscription $(serviceConnection) --query  "privateEndpointConnections[?properties.privateLinkServiceConnectionState.status=='Pending'].id" -o tsv)        
        for endpoint in $endpoints 
        do
          az sql server private-endpoint-connection approve --account-name $1 --name $endpoint --resource-group ${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }} --subscription  $(serviceConnection)
        done
        }


    sqlServers="$(az sql server list -g ${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }} --query '[].name' --subscription $(serviceConnection) -o tsv)"

    for sqlServerName in $sqlServers
    do
        echo "Processing $sqlServerName ========================================="
        enable_sql_private_endpoint  $sqlServerName
    done
```

The code above is executed in a further step in a YAML file and in it's simplest terms:

- YAML Orchestrator File executed via CICD
- Terraform Script called to create resource (code snippet 1)
- Another YAML file executed to approve endpoints using inline Bash (code snippet 2)

The problem is with `az sql server private-endpoint-connection approve` and that it doesn't exist. When I review this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/server?view=azure-cli-latest) I cannot see anything remotely like the approve option for SQL Server Endpoints like what Storage or MySQL have. Any help would be appreciated on how this can be achieved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, this is what I used in my YAML / Bash to get things working:

```
        sqlServers="$(az sql server list -g ${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }} --query '[].name' --subscription $(serviceConnection) -o tsv)"

    for sqlServerName in $sqlServers
    do
      echo "Processing $sqlServerName ========================================="
      enable_sql_private_endpoint  $sqlServerName
    done
```

and

```
        function enable_sql_private_endpoint {
    endpoints=$(az sql server show --name $1 -g ${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }} --subscription $(serviceConnection) --query  "privateEndpointConnections[?properties.privateLinkServiceConnectionState.status=='Pending'].id" -o tsv)        
    for endpoint in $endpoints 
    do
      az network private-endpoint-connection approve -g  ${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }} --subscription $(serviceConnection) --id $endpoint  --type Microsoft.Sql/servers --description "Approved" --resource-name $1
    done
    }
```

With the following line being the key syntax to use if anyone ever encounters such a similar scenario in their CICD with Syanpse and Managed Private Endpoints:

```
az storage account private-endpoint-connection approve --account-name $1 --name $endpoint --resource-group ${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }} --subscription  $(serviceConnection)
```

Answer (score 1):

Code below approves the connection request from Synapse managed private endpoints to storage account and key vault. The Azure CLI in PowerShell syntax was used in Terraform provisioner "local-exec".

The "az storage account show" accepted resource id (--id) as argument, whereas, the "az keyvault show" didn't. So had to parse the key vaults resource id into subscription, resource group and key vault name.

The reason why setting the dependency on time_sleep was because it took some time for Azure Resource Manager to process the creation of Synapse  Managed Private endpoint. Even though code for the creation is not shown here, the whole code where this snippet was extracted from created Synapse workspace and Synapse managed private endpoint for storage account and key vault. Some time gap was required between the creation of managed private endpoint and PE approval.

```html
resource "time_sleep" "wait_for_managed_pe" {   # Wait 1 min after creation of managed private endpoint
  depends_on = [azurerm_synapse_managed_private_endpoint.managed_private_endpoint]
  create_duration = "1m" # Set the delay duration here (e.g., 1 minute)
}

locals {
  
  # Split key vault resource ID by the '/' character
  split_kv_resource_id = split("/", var.managedpe_targets["pe1"].private_connection_endpoint_id)
  # Extract the subscription, resource group and keyvault name using the element function
  subscription          = element(local.split_kv_resource_id, 2)
  resource_group_name   = element(local.split_kv_resource_id, 4)
  keyvault_name         = element(local.split_kv_resource_id, 8)
}

#
# Auto approve the connection request for Synapse managed private endpoint to the storage account
#

resource "null_resource" "private_endpoint_approval" {

  depends_on = [time_sleep.wait_for_managed_pe] # Make sure this resource depends on the time_sleep resource

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = <<-EOT

          # For storage account, extract id list of private endpoint connection in pending approval state.
          $ids = (az storage account show --id ${var.storage_account_id} --query  "privateEndpointConnections[?privateLinkServiceConnectionState.status == 'Pending'].id" -o json) | ConvertFrom-Json 
          Write-Host "Storage PE Pending Connection List: $ids "

          # Approve all the private endpoint connection in the id list
          foreach ($id_item in $ids) {
            az storage account private-endpoint-connection approve --id $id_item
          }

          # For key vault, extract id list of private endpoint connection in pending approval state.
          $ids = (az keyvault show --subscription ${local.subscription} --resource-group ${local.resource_group_name} --name ${local.keyvault_name} --query "properties.privateEndpointConnections[?privateLinkServiceConnectionState.status == 'Pending'].id" -o json) | ConvertFrom-Json 
          Write-Host "Keyvault PE Pending Connection List: $ids "

          # Approve all the private endpoint connection in the id list
          foreach ($id_item in $ids) {
            az keyvault private-endpoint-connection approve --id $id_item
          }
                                                                             
        EOT
    interpreter = ["pwsh", "-Command"]
  }
}
```

After completing the above code using Azure CLI, I was told that az cli may not be stable approach because its syntax, arguments and behavior might change down the road without explicit document or notice.

So, rewrote the code using "azapi" provisioner. First file below is versions.tf which defines Terraform provider version and source. Second one updates the status of private endpoint in storage account and key vault requested by Synapse. It selects PE connection request id in "Pending" state and update it to "Approved".

```html
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0.0"
  backend "azurerm" {}
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      version = "= 3.9.0" 
    }
    azuread = {
      version = "= 2.36.0"
    }
    azapi = {
      version = "= 1.10.0"
      source = "azure/azapi"
    }
  }
}
```

```html
#
# Auto approve the connection request for Synapse managed private endpoint to the storage account
#

data "azapi_resource" "synapse_storage" {
  type                   = "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-09-01"
  resource_id            = var.storage_account_id
  response_export_values = ["properties.privateEndpointConnections"]
}

# Retrieve the private endpoint connection name from the storage account based on the private endpoint name
locals {
  private_endpoint_connections = [
    for connection in jsondecode(data.azapi_resource.synapse_storage.output).properties.privateEndpointConnections : connection
    #    if try(connection.privateLinkServiceConnectionState.status, null) == "Pending"    
    if connection.properties.privateLinkServiceConnectionState.status == "Pending"
  ]
  private_endpoint_connection_names = [for connection in local.private_endpoint_connections : connection.name]
}

# Approve all the private endpoint connection in storage account
resource "azapi_update_resource" "storage_approval" {
  count = length([
    for connection in local.private_endpoint_connection_names : connection
  ])

  type      = "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/privateEndpointConnections@2022-09-01"
  name      = local.private_endpoint_connection_names[count.index]
  parent_id = var.storage_account_id

  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      privateLinkServiceConnectionState = {
        description = "Approved via Terraform, azapi_update_resource."
        status      = "Approved"
      }
    }
  })

  depends_on = [local.private_endpoint_connections]
}

#
# Approve private endpoint connection in key vault
#
# Retrieve private endpoint connection name from key vault.
data "azapi_resource" "synapse_keyvault" {
  type                    = "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2022-07-01"
  resource_id            = var.keyvault_id
  response_export_values = ["properties.privateEndpointConnections"]
}

# Retrieve all the private endpoint id whose connection state is "Pending"
locals {
  kv_private_endpoint_connections = [
    for connection in jsondecode(data.azapi_resource.synapse_keyvault.output).properties.privateEndpointConnections : connection   
      if connection.properties.privateLinkServiceConnectionState.status == "Pending"
  ]
  kv_private_endpoint_id = [for connection in local.kv_private_endpoint_connections : connection.properties.privateEndpoint.id]
}

# Approve all the private endpoint connection request in pending state 
resource "azapi_update_resource" "keyvault_approval" {
  count = length([
    for connection in local.kv_private_endpoint_id : connection
  ])

  type                   =  "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/privateEndpointConnections@2022-07-01"
  name                   = "${basename(local.kv_private_endpoint_id[count.index])}-conn"
  parent_id              = var.keyvault_id

  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      privateLinkServiceConnectionState = {
        description = "Approved via Terraform, azapi_update_resource."
        status      = "Approved"
      }
    }
  })
  
  depends_on = [local.kv_private_endpoint_connections]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Currently, you can't approve a Managed Private Endpoint using Terraform.

**Note:** `Azure PowerShell` and `Azure CLI` are the preferred methods for managing Private Endpoint connections on Microsoft Partner Services or customer owned services.

For more details, refer to [Manage Private Endpoint connections on a customer/partner owned Private Link service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/manage-private-endpoint#manage-private-endpoint-connections-on-a-customerpartner-owned-private-link-service).

Comment: Apologies, I perhaps wasn't clear in my post which I will adjust. The Bash is executed in a further step in yaml. In summary YAML calls a number of scripts including terraform and once that resource is set up, a YAML file is executed to approve any endpoints

Comment: Are you therefore saying that this will work? Approve-AzPrivateEndpointConnection -Name myPrivateEndpointConnection -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -ServiceName myPrivateLinkService